# Edit and Delete an input in C programming

Tags: c

can you please give me a clue of how can i give the user , the ability to delete their houses or edit their inputs like house ID or house area or price by the functions
i would appreciate your help <3

this is my code for a real estate

```
#include <stdio.h>

int userInput();

void addHouse();
void deleteHouse();
void editHouse();
void reportHouse();

struct House
{
int ID[100];
int RP[100];
int MP[100];
int area[100];
int studNum;
float bBalance;
};

int main()
{
//no constants

struct House p[100];

FILE *fp,*fw,*ft;

int sel = 1; //select number for menu

while(userInput){

sel = userInput();

switch(sel){

case 1:
addHouse();
break;

case 2:
deleteHouse();
break;

case  3:
editHouse();
break;

case 4:
reportHouse();
break;

case 0:
break;

}

}

}

int userInput()
{
int choice;

printf("===========================\n");
printf("(1). Add new property\n");
printf("(2). Delete a property\n");
printf("(3). Edit a property\n");
printf("(4). Report properties\n");
printf("(0). Exit\n");
printf("===========================\n\n");

printf("Enter your choice Please\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);

return choice;
}

void addHouse()
{
struct House p[100];

for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
printf("What is the number %d house's ID?\n",i);
scanf(" %d", &p[i].ID);
printf("How much is the number %d house's price for rent?\n",i);
scanf(" %d", &p[i].RP);
printf("How much is the number %d house's price for mortgage?\n",i);
scanf("%d", &p[i].MP);
printf("How much is the number %d house's area?\n",i);
scanf(" %d", &p[i].area);
}
}

void deleteHouse()
{
printf("*edits entry*\n");
}

void editHouse()
{
printf("*deletes entry*\n");
}

void reportHouse()
{
printf("*adds entry\n");
}
```

Comment: `while(userInput){ sel = userInput() ... ` does not do what you think it does. A functionname without the `()` is implicitly converted to a pointer.

Comment: This code is also wrong and will lead to the undefined behavior: `scanf(" %d", &p[i].ID);` `p[i].ID` is `int[100]`, not `int`

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This makes reading it much easier and people are more likely to help you.

Comment: Thank you all for helping about deleteing and element , but what about editing???
@Ari0nhh im sorry i dont understand the problem , do you mind explaining more?:-)
RedX , Thanks for your comment and sorry about that ;)
It's a project for my university

Answer (score 2):

You needed a clue, so here it is:-

You can ask the user to provide you with house ID and according to that, the details of that particular ID will be deleted. 
Like in array, you delete an element from a particular position. In here, you need to have an ID and try to delete the record like you used to delete an element from an array.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the i th structure of an array

```
 MYSTRUCT array[100]; // buffer has room for 100, which is plenty
 int N;               // N is the number we actually have, say ten
 int i = 3;           // index of item to delete


 // formula for deletion. 
 memmove(&array[i], &array[i+1], sizeof(MYSTRUCT) * (N - i - 1));
 N--;
```

Comment: Hi and thannks a lot for the answer ,
can you please use this instuction in an example...i used this as you told me to but im getting errors , i think im doing it wrong